# Stanford NER pyner error: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code in Python and I want to use the Stanford NER for this.
I went to their site: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml#Download
and downloaded the Python version.
I tried to run the example they have on their website, which is:

```
>>> import ner
>>> tagger = ner.HttpNER(host='localhost', port=8080)
>>> tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
```

and supposed to print:

```
{'LOCATION': ['California', 'United States'],
 'ORGANIZATION': ['University of California']}
```

to the screen.
But instead the line: tagger.get_entities("University of California is located in California, United States")
throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ner-0.1-py3.6.egg\ner\client.py", line 81, in get_entities
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ner-0.1-py3.6.egg\ner\client.py", line 165, in tag_text
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I couldn't find a way to fix it.
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I seems that it's trying to access *localhost:8080*. Is a server application running on your machine that listens on that port?

Comment: how do i find out that?
also, I tried defining the tagger with another port, with the line:
tagger = ner.SocketNER(host='localhost',port=9191, output_format='slashTags')
but I still got the same error:
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
and one last thing to be clear - the line that defines the tagger compiles. The only problematic line is the one that calls get_entities

Comment: You can use *netstat* to query your existing connections status. But the error says that it isn't. Im' sorry but i have no *NER* knowledge,  so I can't help you further.

Comment: Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Hey,
So I've been told that the problem is that windows 10 blockes a lot of IP ports, so I unlocked port 8080 but it didn't help.
Any idea why? Or do you think I should hve unlocked a different port?

Comment: I'd suggest to try with a simple client/server setup (if you can't write one, there are many instructions how to write on the internet) to see whether the port is the problem.